# GCC and inlining C functions declared in other files (the "function body not available" problem)

Tags: c, gcc

I am heaving a weird issue with inlining functions defined in different files. Consider the following scenario.

in main.c:

```
#include "inline.h"
int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<=100000; i++) {
        omfg(i);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

in inline.h:

```
inline int omfg(unsigned int num);
```

and in inline.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
inline int omfg(unsigned int num) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<= 10; i++) {
        printf(".");
        num++;
    }
    return num;
 }
```

When I compile with gcc using something similar to:

```
$ gcc inline.c main.c -o binary -Wall -Winline -Wextra -O2
```

I get:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
inline.h:2: warning: inlining failed in call to 'omfg': function body not available
main.c:7: warning: called from here
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I declare `omfg()` in a different way? Its quite puzzling...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the implementation to the header file.  You can declare the function up front then define it below, or even #include a special file like inline.inl at the bottom of the header to hide it, but fundamentally the function definition needs to be available if it's to be inline.

Comment: I have to say, this is a pretty unhelpful comment in some ways.  If you define something in a header file and then do an Objective-C style compilation, it's going to error out because your function is multiply declared.  So... what then?  I'm genuinely curious what the fix for that is, actually.

Comment: What is an Objective-C style compilation?

Comment: one can only use the attribute always_inline with function declarations, but redeclaration with the definition/body in the header results in redefinition of `omfg`, what to do?

Answer (score 2):

You must put the implementation of your inline function in the header file if you want this to compile.

Comment: I think it's true for latest compilers.